# Azure Bus, TokenProvider with ACS Service Identity, using password

Tags: authentication, azure, oauth, swt, servicebus

I am using the Azure Bus for messaging.  We are configuring ACS with proper security practice, i.e. with different relying parties representing different topics & subscriptions.

We are using ACS Service Identity to access the bus.  So far we were using a symmetric key but we are moving to use passwords with those identities.

I am failing to find a way to setup a TokenProvider (to pass to a MessagingFactory) to authenticate my Service Identities.

I've tried:

```
        var serviceUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri(
            "sb",
            serviceBusNamespace,
            string.Empty);
        var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateOAuthTokenProvider(
            new[] { serviceUri },
            new NetworkCredential(serviceIdentityName, serviceIdentityPassword));
```

which throws, complaining about "timeout elapsed upon attempting to obtain a token while accessing 'https://XYZ.servicebus.windows.net/$STS/OAuth/'.".  I know that url isn't the endpoint for o-auth ; I don't know why it's trying to go there.

So I've tried:

```
        var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateOAuthTokenProvider(
            new[] { new Uri("https://XYZ-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13") },
            new NetworkCredential(serviceIdentityName, serviceIdentityPassword));
```

which threw with "timeout elapsed upon attempting to obtain a token while accessing 'https://XYZ-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/$STS/OAuth/'."

Again the url isn't good...

So I changed tactic and tried:

```
        var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(
            serviceIdentityName,
            serviceIdentityPassword);
```

To receive the exception "The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://XYZ-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'"

So...  What is the right incantation to authenticate a service identity using a password?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this

1. Get Wrap Token from ACS using serviceid/password
2. Get Signed SWT using the Wrap Token you got in the first step from ACS again
3. Create a SimpleTokenProvider using the SWT token you got in step 2 (`TokenProvider.CreateSimpleWebTokenProvider`).

This [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh674475.aspx)  has examples to help you  with step 1 and 2. This is bit round about way I guess but if there is a better way, I would like to hear about it. Btw sending just the WRAP token doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well...  the truth is I don't know what to do with TokenProvider.CreateSimpleWebTokenProvider.  A token provider that takes only one token baffles me...  The principle of Service Bus is that each entity (queue, topic & subscription) is modelled as a different relying party, hence you need a different token for each.  I do have code for acquiring oAuth token though...  I might try it.

Comment: So you want different token for each, which is what you anyway need to do if auth is done on entity level,  or you want to do get just one token and use it on all the entities, I guess that can be done adding  namespace as RP,? Sorry I don't understand your problem.